# What is the reason why the Cron job is not working?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Cron does not work, although if you run the script directly, it works.

Tried different options

```
*/2 * * * * bash /var/www/site.com/html/check.sh
```

or so

```
*/2 * * * * /var/www/site.com/html/check.sh
```

In the logs:

Feb 4 08:16:01 CRON [2306]: (root) CMD (bash /var/www/site.com/html/check.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
status=$(curl -I https://example.com 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d$' ' -f2)
if [ $status != "200" ]
then reboot now
fi
```

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: What makes you think it's not working? The log message says it's running the script.

Comment: @Barmar If the script works, it should reload at a certain site status. If I run the script directly, then it works and the server restarts, but this does not happen through the scheduler.

Comment: Without seeing the script it's impossible to say why it doesn't work. But usually the reason why scripts fail in cron is because they depend on environment variables that you set in your shell startup scripts (`.profile` and `.bashrc`) which aren't run by cron.

Comment: If you search [unix.se] you'll find many similar questions. What research have you done?

Comment: Add `2>> /tmp/check.output` to the end of the command. Then you'll see error messages in that file.

Comment: @Barmar I added the script code to the topic.

I tried to find my problem on the Internet, tried different options for writing a task in the scheduler, but nothing helped.

Comment: Are you getting anything in the `check.output` file?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, /var/www/example.com/html/check.sh: line 4: reboot: command not found

Comment: It's like I said. It doesn't have your `PATH` setting so it can't find the reboot command. Use the full path to the command `/sbin/reboot`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much! Now I understand!